# Reopen a ScrollView programmatically created with kotlin and closed by Gone

Tags: kotlin, layout, scrollview

I created a scrollView prgrammatically

extract from .xml file

```
<!-- Spinner -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/myScrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="125dp"
    tools:context=".QuizActivity">

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"/>
</HorizontalScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here .kt code snippet

```
/***************** SCROllL VIEW *****************/
fun showSpinner(show: Boolean) {
    if (linearLayout == null) {
        linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.linear1)
        if (show) {
            val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this)
            ...
            ...
        } else {
            // Close de scrollView
            // TODO: fermer le spinner
            if (linearLayout!! != null) {
                linearLayout!!.visibility = View.GONE

            }

            // TODO: Add a frame auround the scroll view to get a better look
        }
    }
}
```

But now when I need to recreate it using showSpinner(true) again, it recreate but it does not show at screen !

I saw in the debugger that the procedure is made but nothing comes on the screen ?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
android

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are checking if `linearLayout` is null at the beginning of the function.
Since you are setting its value inside the first `if` block, the code won't be executed after the first `showSpinner` method call.

A better practice is to initialize the layouts in your Activity `onCreate` method or Fragment `onCreateView` method (depends on where you have declared this code)

Try to change your code like this (I assume you are in an Activity)

```
private var linearLayout: LinearLayout? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(<your-layout-ID>)

    linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.linear1)
}

fun showSpinner(show: Boolean) {
    if (show) {
        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this)
        ...

        linearLayout?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    } else {
        linearLayout?.visibility = View.GONE
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: In fact, I forgot to delete the "if (linearLayout == null)" before pasted here but the problem was the same. I did now as you wrote and it works as I want. Thankyou Luca.